# vertex displaced dynamic paint canvas does not render

Tags: dynamic-paint, vertex-paint

I am animating a metal object permanently denting a plastic object that it comes into contact with. The white plastic object is using the dynamic paint physics modifier and is set as the canvas. The gray metal object is set as the dynamic paintbrush with vertex displacement so that the plastic dent develops as the metal moves up and down cyclically.

[image: Blender model]

This looks great in the 3D viewport, and animates just as i want. I baked the first 60 frames of the physics cache that are needed to create the dent on its first up and down cycle.

The problem is that the deformed canvas (dented plastic) is not CPU or GPU rendering. It renders with the initial undeformed shape of the plastic in this example of frame 47.

[image]

What do I need to do to get the dynamic paint canvas to render in its displaced vertex state?

I posted the blend file here if needed:

[image]